# Non-exhaustive patterns using if-then-else

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I have the following function:

```
myMaximum [] = error "There is no such thing as 'maximum' in an empty list."
myMaximum [x] = x
myMaximum (x:xs) = if x >= tailMax
                    then x
                    else tailMax
                where tailMax = myMaximum xs
```

I works just fine when I run `myMaximum [1..5]`, but it throws the error defined on the first line when I run `myMaximum [5..1]`. If I take the first line out, it will complain that there is a non-exhaustive pattern on `myMaximum`. But why this pattern is non-exhaustive? And how calling it with `[1..5]` works just fine and `[5..1]` apparently results in empty list argument to `myMaximum`?

Comment: Just a thing, you should change your error message to the standard form of `"[name]: [cause]"`, so this should be `error "myMaximum: empty list"`

Comment: @AJFarmar thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't about your function. It's about range notation. Type `[5..1]` in ghci, and you'll find that you get an empty list.

Haskell range notation defaults to adding one at each step unless you explicitly change it using the `[first,second..last]` notation. Use `[5,4..1]` to get the behavior you're looking for.

If you remove the first version of your function, the pattern is non-exhaustive because no version of your function can match the empty list then.